# Unable to fill the CircleAvatar with the selected image from image_picker

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm getting the image from the `image_picker` package and loading the image in `CircleAvatar` but image is not filling across the circle. I have used `boxfit.fill` in the `ClipRRect` and also in the `ClipOval`.

[image]

```
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

class EditProfileScreen extends StatefulWidget {
static const String routename = "/EditProfileScreen";

const EditProfileScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

@override
_EditProfileScreenState createState() => _EditProfileScreenState();
}

class _EditProfileScreenState extends BaseState<EditProfileScreen> {
  final ImagePicker _picker = ImagePicker();
  XFile? _imageFileSelected;
  set _imageFile(XFile? value) {
  _imageFileSelected = value == null ? null : value;
  }

void _onImageButtonPressed(ImageSource source,
  {BuildContext? context, bool isMultiImage = false}) async {
try {
  final pickedFile = await _picker.pickImage(
      source: source, maxHeight: 160, maxWidth: 200);
  setState(() {
    _imageFile = pickedFile;
  });
} catch (e) {
  setState(() {
    _pickImageError = e;
  });
}
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: AppWidgets.backgroundColor,
  appBar: AppWidgets.appbar(text: "Edit Profile", actionWidgets: []),
  body: SingleChildScrollView(
child: Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 16, 20, 20),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Center(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                CircleAvatar(
                  child: ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(48),
                    child: (_imageFileSelected?.path == null)
                        ? Image.network(
                            profileImagePath,
                          )
                        : Image.file(
                            File(_imageFileSelected!.path),
                          ),
                  ),
                  radius: 50.0,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 10,
                ),
                TextButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    _onImageButtonPressed(ImageSource.gallery,
                        context: context);
                  },
                  child: AppWidgets.text(
                      string: 'Change Photo',
                      weight: FontWeight.w500,
                      textColor: AppWidgets.buttonColor,
                      size: 16),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
      ),
);
}
```

Note:
I have used boxfit no luck.
I tried clipoval in the child didn't work.
I tried to put images in backgroundImage and foregroundImage unable to do

Comment: you can try the fit as cover ```fit: BoxFit.cover```

Comment: i tried with boxfit.cover also it's not working @JayGadariya

Comment: Try removing the ClipRRect.

Comment: what should i have to put in the place of ClipRRect @Josteve

Comment: Don't replace it with anything at all..Just remove it, leave only the CircleAvatar as the parent of the image.

Comment: @Josteve image will come in rectangle form

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using circleavatar you can use Container with background property Try this code.

```
Container(
height: 88.5.h,
width: 88.5.w,
decoration: BoxDecoration(
image: DecorationImage(
fit: BoxFit.cover,
image:  CachedNetworkImageProvider(
state.details["profile_photo"]),
shape: BoxShape.circle,
border: Border.all(
color: ColorConstant.buttonColor,
width: 5.w)),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this to store the updated picture locally.
ps. this already has a picture which can be changed but you can just use background color to hold instead.

```
    File _image;
  String _imagepath;

  Future _getImage() async {
    var image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    if (image != null) {
      var cropped = await ImageCropper.cropImage(
        sourcePath: image.path,
        maxHeight: 100,
        maxWidth: 100,
        aspectRatio: CropAspectRatio(ratioX: 1, ratioY: 1),
        cropStyle: CropStyle.circle,
        compressQuality: 100,
      );
      this.setState(() {
        _image = cropped;
      });
      saveImage(_image.path);
    }
  }

  void saveImage(path) async {
    SharedPreferences saveimage = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    saveimage.setString('imagepath', path);
  }

  void LoadImage() async {
    SharedPreferences saveimage = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      _imagepath = saveimage.getString('imagepath');
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    LoadImage();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: _getImage,
      child: Container(
        //padding: EdgeInsets.all(2),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(
            color: Colors.white,
            width: 5.0,
          ),
          shape: BoxShape.circle,
        ),

        child: _imagepath != null
            ? CircleAvatar(
                backgroundImage: FileImage(File(_imagepath)),
                radius: 60,
              )
            : CircleAvatar(
                backgroundImage: _image != null
                    ? FileImage(_image)
                    : AssetImage('assets/mypic1.jpg'),
                backgroundColor: Colors.blue[200],
                radius: 60,
              ),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).